# Async processing inside a Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I have a request handler which does some heavy lifting inside and takes about 5 secs to return. The request returns a Model which includes 3 collections. The heaviest collection takes about 2 secs to process and they are all independent. I wanted to try and run them in parallel inside the request but nothing I have tried seems to work. What I am seeing is that tomcat handles the first few requests but pretty soon it just chokes and stops.

Here is what Iv'e tried:

1. I have a utility that takes Callable's, runs them on a pretty big Executor, and returns FutureTasks.

   ```
   public class Async {

       public static boolean active = true;
       private static ExecutorService exe = active ? Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50) : null;

       public static FutureTask run(Callable callable) throws Exception {
           FutureTask f = new FutureTask(callable);
           if (active) {
               exe.execute(f);
           } else {
               f.run();
           }
           return f;
       }
   }
   ```
2. And i use it like this:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/test")
   public
   @ResponseBody
   MessageDto authenticate(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

   final Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

   FutureTask future1 = Async.run(new Callable() {
       @Override
       public Object call() throws Exception {
           try {
               [SOME PROCESS THAT TAKES ABOUT 2 SECS]
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               LOG.error(ex);
           }
           return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
       }
   });

   FutureTask future2 = Async.run(new Callable() {
       @Override
       public Object call() throws Exception {
           try {
               [SOME PROCESS THAT TAKES ABOUT 2 SECS]
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               LOG.error(ex);
           }
           return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
       }
   });

   FutureTask future3 = Async.run(new Callable() {
       @Override
       public Object call() throws Exception {
           try {
               [SOME PROCESS THAT TAKES ABOUT 1 SEC]
           } catch (Exception ex) {
               LOG.error(ex);
           }
           return null;  //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
       }
   });

   future1.get();
   future2.get();
   future3.get();

   return new MessageDto(responseMap);
   }
   ```

I've also tried using Spring's @Async but same result, server getting stuck.
Please help
Thanks

Comment: Hi Or. Nice Question! take a look at this tutorial, I think the second way (Spring Thread Pool + Spring non-managed bean example) should work fine for you. I've already did something similar. http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-and-java-thread-example/

Comment: You should also look into servlet async processing since Servlet 3.0.